# Plotting a vertical line using axvline by referencing a datetime index value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a bar chart that draws a vertical line at a specific index reference. Inexplicably, when I try to plot a dataframe with a datetime index, the vertical line never appears. However there is no problem with an 'int' index.

Changing the individual datetime index values from Timestamps to datetime did not help.

This code works:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index, kind="bar", stacked=True)
ax.axvline(x=df.index[40], linewidth = 10, color='k', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

This code does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numdays = 50
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)][::-1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index=date_list)
ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index, kind="bar", stacked=True)
ax.axvline(x=df.index[40], linewidth = 10, color='k', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

I would have thought that setting ax.axvline(x=df.index[40],...) would behave identically in both cases, as the 40th element of the df.index list is also the 40th x-value in the plot. However I cannot get this to work for a datetime index. I would really like to avoid having to change my entire dataframe index from datetime to int but if that is the only solution, so be it.

Thanks.

Edit: Set datetime index for the second code snippet's dataframe.

Comment: I think your second code misses something; else it's the same as the first one.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest, yes you're right, I did not define the index in the second example. Fixed

Comment: Oh, just use `x=40`.

Comment: That works, thanks! Can you explain why? I thought that passing a dataframe to matplotlib created x-values that matched the dataframe index. Are the x-values actually ordinal numbers (x=50 is the 50th item, even if my index is strings)?

Comment: All correct. But you are using pandas plotting method, not matplotlib's. Pandas bar plots will plot ordinal numbers.